# bash compare a string vs a list of strings

Tags: regex, bash

Suppose I have the following code in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

bad_fruit=( apple banana kiwi )
for fname in `ls`
do
  # want to check if fname contains one of the bad_fruit
  is_bad_fruit=??? # <------- fix this line
  if [ is_bad_fruit ]
  then
    echo "$fname contains bad fruit in its name"
  else
    echo "$fname is ok"
  fi
done
```

**How do I fix is_bad_fruit so that it is true if fname contains one of the bad_fruit strings?**

Comment: `for fname in *` is much better than ``for fname in `ls` `` (if filenames contain whitespace)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following code :

```
#!/bin/bash

bad_fruit=( apple banana kiwi )
re="$(printf '%s\n' "${bad_fruit[@]}" | paste -sd '|')"

for fname in *; do
  # want to check if fname contains one of the bad_fruit
  if [[ $fname =~ $re ]]; then
    echo "$fname contains bad fruit in its name"
  else
    echo "$fname is ok"
  fi
done
```

Take care of [*useless use of ls*](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#ls)

*`ls` is a tool for interactively looking at file information. Its output is formatted for humans and will cause bugs in scripts. Use globs or find instead. Understand why* : http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: +1 looks like it works well - somehow, I run into trouble when I try to stuff the rest of that last grep into a boolean variable and then using the if on that boolean variable.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Give me some examples please, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: is_bad_fruit=\`echo "$fname" | grep &>/dev/null -E "$re"\`  # this seems to be always true

Comment: What do you want to store in is_bad_fruit variable ?

Comment: true if the fname contains one of the bad fruit and false if it doesn't

Comment: The `if echo "$fname" | grep &>/dev/null -E "$re"` line can be substitued by `if [[ $fname =~ $re ]]`. POST edited.

Comment: Very nice trick - turning the list into a regex before matching.  Also learned about the extraneous ls.  I appreciate you taking your time to teach me some bash.

Comment: You could move the regex definition line `re=...` out of the loop (no need to do it repeatedly, since it doesn't depend on `fname`)

Comment: I find the construction of the regex pattern a bit strange. Do you know what happens if the bad_fruit array is longer?

Comment: No, but maybe you will tell us if you know something ?!

Answer (score 2):

Another option (using `grep` with an inner loop and evaluating the exit code):

```
#!/bin/bash

bad_fruit=( apple banana kiwi )
for fname in *; do
  for fruit in "${bad_fruit[@]}"; do
    echo "$fruit"
  done | grep "$fname"
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "$fname contains bad fruit in its name"
  else
    echo "$fname is ok"
  fi
done
```